# derby equivalent for find_in_set of Mysql

Tags: mysql, database, derby

I am looking for the derby equivalent for find_in_set of Mysql. In mysql,

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET('b','a,b,c,d');
```

I plan to migrate db to derby from mysql. how to achieve it for the Derby? 
locate() function can not achieve the same since the comma separted string is regards as a set.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good use of Derby's CREATE FUNCTION feature: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/ref/rrefcreatefunctionstatement.html

Create a custom function in Derby which implements the mysql FIND_IN_SET function.

You might try asking on the derby-user mailing list; some other user might have already written such a function.